# How to Handle Storage in OOP

Tags: c#, arrays, oop

I'm trying to learn OOP programming, but whenever I'm designing my programs I get to a certain point and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Basically lets say my program deals with **Students** and **Teachers**, I have multiple GUIs that are used to input and output information from these two classes. I require an array for both **Students** and **Teachers**, however this array, or at least parts of the array are required in almost every windows form.

Now I know its bad practice to have public variables, but I find it so much easier to make a static class called **Storage** which holds all my arrays of data, which then each form can edit these arrays from the static class, is this massively breaking the principles of OOP. And if it is, in which class should I be generating my arrays to store all my data in, and how should this data be passed around to allow the certain forms to access it?

Coding in c#, if that affects anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is for a switch from so-called god object to dependency injection. Lets say you have storage like:

```
public static class GodObjectStorage {
  public static Teacher GetTeacher(int teacherID);
  public static Student GetStudent(int studentID);
}
```

Instead you create interface to storage like

```
public interface IStorage {
  Teacher GetTeacher(int teacherID);
  Student GetStudent(int studentID);
}
```

And admit that dependency on every single class consuming the storage - like

```
public class FormMain {
  private readonly IStorage m_Storage;
  public FormMain(IStorage storage) {
    m_Storage = storage;
  }
}
```

Main benefit of this approach is that you can unit-test your stuff and also it kinds of self-organize your code (you see all the external dependencies - like dependency on storage in constructor). There are also frameworks (like Unity, Ninject, etc.) that can help you with the DI.

If don't want to deal with DI framework, the poor-man solution is singleton pattern.

```
public class Storage : IStorage {
   private Storage() { ... }
   public static readonly IStorage Instance = new Storage();
}
```

Also note - in real world you're most likely to work with so-called dettached objects (i.e. your POC classes like Student or Teacher will represent some state of persistent storage at time of retrieval - like some DB/file/cloud service). If you don't want to run into a problem once you need to switch to "persistent" world you should design your Storage class like

```
public interface IStorage {
  Teacher GetTeacher(int teacherID);
  void SaveTeacher(Teacher teacher);
}
```

And the changes of `Teacher` class retrieved via `GetTeacher` shouldn't be persisted until you explicitly call `SaveTeacher`.

Comment: Thank-you this is really helpful :)

Comment: Another question though, would I create the initial storage object in my first form, and then pass it down though dependency injection to all other forms that require the information.